# What's the difference between JdbcCursorItemReader and ItemReader/JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to confirm my understanding about the **difference** between  `JdbcCursorItemReader` and a class that `implements ItemReader` that uses `JdbcTemplate` for querying the db.

Is this the difference? Normally `ItemReader` finishes fetching everything before `ItemWriter.write(List<T> items)` is called. But for `JdbcCursorItemReader`, as soon as it reads one record, `ItemWriter.read()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the docs for `JdbcCursorItemReader`:

> Simple item reader implementation that opens a JDBC cursor and
>   continually retrieves the next row in the ResultSet.

So for your question - yes, that's the difference. And personally, I would recommend `JdbcCursorItemReader` or `JdbcPagingItemReader` instead of `ItemReader`, because you can access data little faster with them, based on my experience.

Comment: If it's true, there are cases you wouldn't want `JdbcCursorItemReader` though if you want all your data to be present during `ItemWriter.write()`.

Comment: for this type of requirement, you could use a taskletstep without any need of reader/writer, because you obviously do not need the chunk oriented approach